# Set acl in haproxy based on client ip using map_ip

Tags: acl, haproxy, haproxy-ingress

In haproxy configs, I need to be able to look up the client ip of a request in a map of IP cidrs and then set an acl if the client ip exists in the map

We can assume that I have a map ***<path_to_map/ipcidrs.map>***
which is populated like this:

```
1.12.123.12/24  1.12.123.12/24
```

We can also assume that i have a txn variable that gives us the IP
***txn.ip***

I've tried this:

```
acl is_IP_in_map var(txn.ip),map_ip(<path_to_map>/ipcidrs.map)
```

I noticed that the acl was not being set.

Is there something that i am missing here? Can anyone suggest alternatives?

**Things to consider:**

> 1. I'm aware that I can use a list, but I think I need to use a map because the map is being dynamically updated via the runtime
>    client(updateMap). Im assuming that list updates are more expensive
>    that map updates. Hence the choice for maps.
> 2. the ipcidrs.map contains cidrs. Hence the need for map_ip. Simple string matching could have worked were the map filled with IPs.
> 3. Yes, the value in the map is redundant. but this is based on point 1 where i need to key off the client IP based on the cidr value.